# Choosing design pattern when sending request of same base type

Tags: c#

I have problem choosing design pattern in the described below case:
I have requests, that are basically same, but everyone is adding some more properties, example: `Animal` is `BaseClass` with some properties(`bool Color{get; set;}`....), Cat and Dog have to derive Animal, but adding some more properties, for example `Dog => bool IsBarking {get; set; }` and `Cat bool isMewIng {get; set;};` This requests will be send to server, that will process them differently base on request type, but there will be some properties of the requests that will be processed equally.For example `public void  Validation(request)`
will be same for all the requests...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Sounds like homework?

Comment: Specific questions about design are better suited for http://programmers.stackexchange.com, although they might see this as opinion based.

Comment: @NexTerren when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Comment: @gnat Fair enough, the intent with my comment was "ask this question there _instead_" and not "ask it there _as well_."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a good candidate for the Visitor pattern.

Lets take the following base class:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public abstract int Legs { get; }
    public virtual void Speak() { Console.WriteLine("..."); }
    public abstract void Accept(IAnimalVisitor visitor);
}
```

Notice the accept method. This is where the magic will happen with our Visitor object.

We'll implement these as our derived animals that we need to process.

```
public class Cat : Animal {
    public bool IsMewling { get; set; }
    public override int Legs { get; } = 4;
    public override void Accept(IAnimalVisitor visitor) { visitor.Visit(this); }
    public override void Speak() { Console.WriteLine("Meow"); }
}

public class Dog : Animal {
    public bool IsBarking { get; set; }
    public override int Legs { get; } = 4;
    public override void Accept(IAnimalVisitor visitor) { visitor.Visit(this); }
    public override void Speak() { Console.WriteLine("Woof"); }
}
```

Okay, very good. A couple of booleans of differing property names we may need to check. Lets implement the IAnimalVisitor interface.

```
public interface IAnimalVisitor {
    void Visit(Dog dog);
    void Visit(Cat cat);
}
```

And finally, lets create an implementation that see's if the animal happens to be speaking and acts differently depending on the condition.

```
public class LetsHearWhatItHasToSay : IAnimalVisitor {
    public void Visit(Dog dog) {
        if (dog.IsBarking) dog.Speak();
        else Console.WriteLine("Good boy!");
    }
    public void Visit(Cat cat) {
        if (cat.IsMewling) cat.Speak();
        else Console.WriteLine("Pretty kitty");
    }
}
```

Okay, great. Lets tie it all together in a small sample.

```
void Main()
{
  var animals = new List<Animal>
  {
    new Cat { IsMewling = true },
    new Dog { IsBarking = false },
    new Cat { IsMewling = false },
    new Dog { IsBarking = true }
  };
  var visitor = new LetsHearWhatItHasToSay();
  foreach (var animal in animals)
  {
    animal.Accept(visitor);
  }
}
```

And we get our expected outputs

```
Meow
Good boy!
Pretty kitty
Woof
```

The advantages to using visitor in this case are that we can create an arbitrary number of encapsulated objects that can handle different types of logical operations over the class hierarchy in a type-safe way without having to make modifications to that class hierarchy. The disadvantage is that when you add an additional Animal that your want to visit, you have to update every visitor that works on the hierarchy.